# How to make a POST request from ASIHTTPRequest to Rails that gets inserted into DB

Tags: iphone, ruby-on-rails-3

Newbie to iOS. I have a rails blog application with a Post model that I created with scaffold. It has a name:string and an image. I am using ASIHTTPRequest to create a new post. It connects to the server fine, but the parameters "name" and "image" don't get passed correctly into the database. Here's the iphone code:

```
NSURL *url=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://localhost:3000/posts"];
    ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"name"];
    [request setFile:@"/Users/Seb/Desktop/beach.jpeg" forKey:@"image"]; 
    [request startSynchronous];
```

Here's what the rails server log shows:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at Wed May 04 15:41:43 -0700 2011
  Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"name"=>"Ben", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x103eb33a0 @content_type="image/jpeg", @original_filename="beach.jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"; filename=\"beach.jpeg\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/PI/PI+kcHrCHfuDh-K+ppxAxE+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20110504-11613-zvv5im-0>>}
MONGODB blog_development['posts'].insert([{"_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4dc1d627be2eec2d5d00000f')}])
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/4dc1d627be2eec2d5d00000f
Completed 302 Found in 5ms
```

As you can see, the name and image don't get inserted into the db.  When I do the post from a browser, the server log shows:

```
Started POST "/posts" for 127.0.0.1 at Mon May 02 00:54:52 -0700 2011
  Processing by PostsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"commit"=>"Create Post", "post"=>{"name"=>"tiny face", "image"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x1042b2bb8 @content_type="image/png", @original_filename="Screen shot 2011-05-01 at 11.23.23 PM.png", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"post[image]\"; filename=\"Screen shot 2011-05-01 at 11.23.23 PM.png\"\r\nContent-Type: image/png\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/PI/PI+kcHrCHfuDh-K+ppxAxE+++TI/-Tmp-/RackMultipart20110502-11613-u7czau-0>>}, "authenticity_token"=>"i+4h+XOOuJyTnF+quru8yrBuM1ixlDXC5udYaB/0jP4=", "utf8"=>"✓"}
MONGODB blog_development['posts'].insert([{"name"=>"tiny face", "image_filename"=>"screen_shot_2011-05-01_at_11.23.23_pm.png", "_id"=>BSON::ObjectId('4dbe634dbe2eec2d5d000002')}])
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/posts/4dbe634dbe2eec2d5d000002
Completed 302 Found in 518ms
```

Any idea how to structure my POST to make it save into db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put the name of the table that you are posting to in brackets before the key name. I had exactly the same problem with posting to a rails app.

```
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"table [name]"];
[request setFile:@"/Users/Seb/Desktop/beach.jpeg" forKey:@"table [image]"];
```

Comment: did you get an error like this once you did that?

BSON::InvalidDocument (Cannot serialize an object of class ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile into BSON.):
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:47:in `create'
  app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:46:in `create'

Comment: It might not be the exact code as I'm posting from work but I will check when I get home and look at the code that I used.

Comment: Corrected: brackets should be around the field name not the table name

Comment: thanks. did you also send an authenticity token along with the request?